# clone git repository in gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I need help about gitlab runner. I would need to clone an other repository of gitlab where the runner is launched.

For example: CI runner **runner-repo-a** executed in the **repo-a** and I need to clone **repo-b** in **runner-repo-a**.

Now I have:

```
GO_CHEF: git.developers.mycompany.com/chef/myrepo-chef-repo.git
[...]
Update databags:
  stage: update
  script:
    - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.developers.mycompany.com:".insteadOf "https://git.developers.mycompany.com"
    - go get -u ${GO_CHEF}
```

and this is the error:

```
package git.developers.mycompany.com/chef/myrepo-chef-repo.git: cannot download,         
git://git.developers.mycompany.com/chef/myrepo-chef-repo uses insecure protocol
```

Regards,

Comment: This error may be due to the `https` protocol which is being used. Please try the `SSH` version of `git clone` .

Comment: @mdabdullah I get this error: "remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.developers.mycompany.com:/chef/myrepo-chef-repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
package git.developers.mycompany.com/chef/myrepo-chef-repo: exit status 128"

Comment: Yes 403 is user password/authorization error. You need to generate an SSH key in the machine from which you are `cloning` and add that key into GitLab. Please refer this to generate SSH Key `https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/` , once that is done, refer this to understand how the `rsaxxxx.pub` is to be added to GitLab `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gitlab/gitlab_ssh_key_setup.htm`

Comment: But do you need to generate and add ssh key in the gitlab runner to clone a other repository????

Comment: I guess not. Can you SSH into your Runner and try to clone manually?

Comment: Yeah, it's working. Thank you @mdabdullah for you support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error could be due to the `https` protocol being used in your environment. An easier way would be to just use the `SSH` version of `git clone`.

You need to generate an SSH key in the machine from which you are cloning and add that key into GitLab. Please refer [this](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/) to generate SSH Key , once that is done, refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gitlab/gitlab_ssh_key_setup.htm) to understand how the `rsaxxxx.pub` is to be added to into GitLab.